# CSS change font if not available

Tags: css, macos, safari

Some of you already know, Safari on Mac change the font face to default
if the font set on the page is not available.

I want to change the default font on Safari by setting css file in it.

Is there any command set default font on any page in css?

Comment: Use [`font-family`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include multiple fonts in the `font-family` attribute: if one isn't available the next one in the list is used. For example, this will use Arial if "custom font"isn't available:

```
html {
    font-family: "custom font", Arial;
}
```